# Как сравнить два массива разной длины и вернуть массив с их общими значениями

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пример:

```
arr1 [1,2,3,4,5,8,11,16,19]  
arr2 [90,54,34,12,1,2,3,4,5,7,82]
```

Должно вернуть:

```
arr3 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

И еще, как вернуть массив порядковых номеров этих значений в первом массиве? То есть вернуть массив

```
arr4[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Можно сравнить их м помощью 2 циклов. Пример вот за этой [сылкой](http://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript/thread835674.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 16, 19];
var arr2 = [90, 54, 34, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 82];
        
var arr3 = arr1.filter(function(n){
    return arr2.indexOf(n) >= 0;
});

console.info(arr3);
```

А можно решить задачу "в лоб":

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 16, 19];
var arr2 = [90, 54, 34, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 82];
    
function intersection(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length <= arr2.length) {
        var result = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i)
            for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; ++j)
                if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                    result.push(arr1[i]);
                    break;
                }

        return result;
    }
    return intersection(arr2, arr1);
}

console.info(intersection(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: А можно существующей библиотекой, например https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersection

Comment: Первое можно записать короче (но менее кроссбраузерно) `var arr3 = arr1.filter(n=>arr2.includes(n));`

Comment: А как вернуть массив порядковых номеров этих значений в первом массиве?
То есть :
`arr1 -  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 90, 67]        arr2 -  [5, 17, 54, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 90, 67] ` Вернуть массив `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @KristinaKuli Во втором варианте убрать проверку длин, рекурсивный вызов `intersection` и заменить `result.push(arr1[i])` на `result.push(i)`.